# PyQt window running for x seconds

Tags: python, python-2.7, pyqt4

Is it possible to make PyQt window stay opened for x seconds, and then pass?

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
#enough code?

#pass to rest of the code?
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use a timer to close the window.

```
if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtGui.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(2000, MainWindow.close)
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Another aproach would be to use a QDialog for showing your ui, calling `exec_` of the dialog instead of the QApplication

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question a solution would be make usage of the `time.sleep` before passing the command to close the window.

```
import time
time.sleep(2) # delays for 2 seconds
```

Comment: That sleep doesn't allow the Qt event loop to continue executing in order to mantain the window responsive